# FlatList react native auto center

Tags: react-native, scroll, center, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I write this code:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
        data={data}
        style={styles.menu}
        renderItem={({item, index})=>
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.menuItem}>
                    <Text style={item.active ? styles.menuItemTextActive : {}}>{item.title}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        }
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        horizontal
    />
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    menu:{
        width: "100%",
        paddingVertical: 5,
        flexGrow: 0,
    },
    menuItem:{
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginHorizontal: 3,
    },
});
```

But items is automatic scroll to center like this picture:
[image]

I do not want this. I want them all to be normally the same as right or left. Like blew picture:
[image]

I also reset the NodeJS server cache but the problem was still not resolved. The first time I wrote there was no problem, I do not know why this problem arose at once

This is my data If it helps:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
        {
            title: 'پرفروش‌ترین‌ها',
            order: '`buy` DESC',
            active: true
        },
        {
            title: 'پرسودترین‌ها',
            order: '(`price` - `primary_price`) DESC',
            where: '`primary_price` > 0'
        },
        {
            title: 'کم‌فروش‌ترین‌ها',
            order: '`buy` ASC',
        },
        {
            title: 'کم‌ترین موجودی',
            order: '`qty`',
            where: '`qty` > -1'
        },
        {
            title: 'کم‌سودترین‌ها',
            order: '(`price` - `primary_price`) ASC',
            where: '`primary_price` > 0'
        },
        {
            title: 'بیش‌ترین موجودی',
            order: '`qty` DESC',
            where: "`qty` > -1 AND `qty` != ''"
        },
        {
            title: 'پرسودترین فاکتورها',
            order: '`profit` DESC',
            where: '`profit` > 0',
            type: 'invoice'
        },
        {
            title: 'پرتعدادترین فاکتورها',
            order: '`count` DESC',
            type: 'invoice'
        },
        {
            title: 'گران‌ترین‌‌ها',
            order: '`price` DESC',
        },
        {
            title: 'ارزان‌ترین‌ها',
            order: '`price` ASC',
        },
        {
            title: 'بدون‌نام‌ها',
            where: "`name` = ''",
            
        },
        {
            title: 'بدون‌موجودی‌ها',
            order: '`qty` DESC',
            where: "`qty` < 1",
            
        },
        {
            title: 'بدون‌قیمت‌خریدها',
            where: "`primary_price` < 1",
            
        },
    ]);
```

Comment: I ran your code and it starts from the left, not from the center. Is data being added to? Where is that set?

Comment: yes i use state for data

Comment: Can you show all the code used to setData?

Comment: @SajadSpeed add `inverted={true}` as props to Flatlist and check.

Comment: not working....

Comment: I add the data to my question

Comment: Now that I check, I noticed that when the data enters the FlatList, it automatically scrolls in the center. if knowing this will help

Answer (score 1):

```
export const MyStyledList = styled(FlatList).attrs({
  contentContainerStyle: {
    flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center'
  },
})``;
```

instead of FlatList render `MyStyledList`

Comment: not working....

Comment: @SajadSpeed try this {flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}

Comment: I try and not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use contentContainerStyle prop of the flat list and align the items in the center.it should look something like this.

```
   contentContainerStyle={{
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
```

Comment: no it's not working